# Junit testing in Intellij

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

The test in

```
/home/nhamoinesu/NetBeansProjects/Dancerocket/src/test/java/com/dancerockit/video/YouTubeTests/TestVideo.java

uses Video.java

which is in

/home/nhamoinesu/NetBeansProjects/Dancerocket/src/main/java/com/dancerockit/video/persistence/domain/Video.java

The test is throwing the following error
java: package com.dancerockit.video.persistence.domain does not exist

Where should the tests live relative to the classes being tested in Inteliij?
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter, so long as both classes are on the classpath.  Are they different projects?  Does IntelliJ register them as separate projects that have no dependencies/relationships to one another?  What happens if you delete the import statement and let IntelliJ import the class for you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "src/main/java" is added as a source folder in your project, and that "src/test/java" is added as a test source folder.